# How to combine multiple docker build statements to create single container

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I have three " docker build --build-arg value -t value -f value " statements used for building separate docker containers.

Is there a way combine them to create a single container ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all with docker build you are creating images not containers. If i understood correctly you want to create a single image from multiple DockerFiles, right? If yes, you can combine your code in a single dockerFile using multi-stage build as shown [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).